# Progress Bar for simple backup script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am not a programmer at all, however I am teaching myself bash scripting and I have a need for a backup script to backup my VMs (I am using KVM/QEMU). I know that you can do snapshots but I need something more permanent a hard copy of the VM if you will and be able to put these on my ZFS Storage system. So I was thinking to write a backup script that runs via cron once a week or so. The file is of course qcow2 or whatever file system is chosen. So far I have a good start on the script.

Some parts of this script has been borrowed from another author

```
### kvm-backup.0.0.1 ###

#!/bin/bash
# Get the date #
BACKUPTIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`  # Affixing the date
# Create the backup file and cp to Destination for backups #
DESTINATION=/mnt/backups/backup-$BACKUPTIME.tar.gz
# Need to define the source folder #
SOURCEFOLDER=/mnt/VMs/

# create backup now #
tar -cpzf $DESTINATION $SOURCEFOLDER
```

**### Right here I need a progress bar but I am not sure how put it all together I know the code above will have to be fitted in to one of the progress bar scripts. I am just not smart enough to put it all together. ###**

Could someone help me out a little bit,
Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

```
tar cpzf - $DESTINATION -P | pv -s $(du -sb $DESTINATION | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > $BACKUPTIME.tar.gz
```